# Why does PyCharm formatter append a new line in <script> and <style> tags whenever a HTML file is reformatted?

Tags: html, pycharm, formatter

If a HTML document looks like :

```
<style>
h1 {text-align:center;}
</style>
.
.
.
.
.
<script>
var a;
</script>
```

then after formatting the HTML file by using either ( `Code` > `Reformat File...` ) or `Ctrl+Alt+L` , the HTML file looks like :

```
<style>
h1 {text-align:center;}
           <!-- New line got appended -->
</style>
.
.
.
.
.
<script>
var a;
             <!-- New line got appended -->
</script>
```

So how we can stop this appending of new line in `<script>` and `<style>` tags whenever the HTML file is reformatted in PyCharm ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way to stop appending of new line in `<script>` and `<style>` tags whenever the HTML file is reformatted in PyCharm is to go to :

`File` > `Settings...` > `Editor` > `Code Style` > `HTML` > `Other` > `Keep white spaces inside:`

Then add the value `,script,style` to the `Keep white spaces inside:`

[image]